# Open OneNote from my Ipad Application - Need OneNote URL SCHEME?

Tags: objective-c, onenote

When I use ***onenote://*** for opening OneNote from my ipad Application, it opens OneNote but gives an error message that says

> Cannot Open Link" There’s a problem with this link in One Note.

This is my Code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"onenote://"]];
```

PS: OneNote for Ipad already has to be installed in the Ipad Device before trying this.

> Is this the right URL SCHEME for OneNote - onenote://
>
> Or am I doing it wrong.

The Error Message does note create a problem when closed, but I just want to get rid of the Error Message. 
Also can parameters be passed to OneNote from my Application.

Help Appreciated!!

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Not Yet! My App just needs a simple redirect to OneNote Ipad App from my App. onenote:// gives me an error which Nick explained that its missing the destination in the URL Scheme.
I dont yet know the right redirect. 
Looking out for a solution!

Comment: From my understanding, in order to make it load without the alert, a page has to be created using the one note api which will return a URL Scheme that can be used to open the app. I haven't tried it yet, but the returned URL is in the format of "onenote://"

Comment: Should I be using the OneNote Api to create a page?
Can I note manually reach out to a page that is already created by the User? Or create a page with the parameters?

Comment: You would need to send authentication details to the API first to get a page that is created by a User. OneNote app requires a Micrsoft ID to use.

Answer (score 3):

Using "onenote-cmd://" should open up OneNote without any errors.

Comment: Just found this answer and it was very helpful! Do you know why this URL differs from the one in the other answers? Cheers, Oliver

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is that the iOS OneNote client doesn't support being launched by a protocol handler without having parameters completed for notebook, section, and page (it doesn't know where to navigate to).If you're just using `onenote://` without specifying a destination, it's "by design" that you will receive an error.

We recommend you link to a specific page when opening OneNote from your application to avoid the error. The OneNote REST API returns a link to the page you've created when Creating a Page, and you can also retrieve a link using the "Copy Link to Page" function from within the iOS app.

Comment: Hi Nick,
"Copy Link to Page" in OneNote Client redirects the App user to open a web OneNote link. I would want to open the Client Ipad OneNote App from my App. 

But redirecting to the OneNote Ipad App, how do I pass parameters with onenote:// or how do I reach the general Notebook, section or page? 
Is there a link or tutorial that can help me with that.
**My App just needs a simple redirect to OneNote Ipad App from my App.** 
Also for multiple users I wouldnt be able to hardcode their specific page even if they have one?
Thanks for your help

Comment: After copying hte link, the clipboard shoudl contain both a web link AND a onenote: protocol link.  Unfortunately there's really not a way to do the non-specific 'app open' that you need at present.  Can you go and raise a new request at onenotedev.uservoice.com please and we'll get it on our backlog for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick pointed out, the OneNote app needs additional parameters to open successfully, without showing the "Cannot Open Link" alert. Here is what I did to solve the problem:

**Note: In my app, the user is already logged in using the LiveSDK (Microsoft Account Login) so I have their Access Token saved.**

I created an "Authorize OneNote" method that sends a request to the OneNote API to create a "Page" in the User's default notebook:

```
(void)AuthorizeOneNote
{
    NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];
    NSString *simpleHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"<html>"
                            "<head>"
                            "<title>\"%@\"</title>"
                            "<meta name=\"created\" content=\"%@\" />"
                            "</head>"
                            "<body>"
                            "<p></p>"
                            "</body>"
                            "</html>", @"Page Title", date];

    NSData *presentation = [simpleHtml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *endpointToRequest = @"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages";
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endpointToRequest]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = presentation;
    [request addValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request setValue:[@"Bearer " stringByAppendingString:@"LIVE-ID-ACCESS-TOKEN"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    objConnectionOneNote = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}
```

This is how I handle the response:

```
(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{  
    if (connection == objConnectionOneNote)
    {
        NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:objData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictData1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        dictData1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        oneNoteClientUrl = [dictData1 valueForKeyPath:@"links.oneNoteClientUrl.href"];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@",oneNoteClientUrl);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@",strData);

        // Launch OneNote Client
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"onenote://"]])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:oneNoteClientUrl]];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote-for-iphone/id410395246?mt=8&uo=4"]];
        }

    }
```

There are couple things to note here:

- This will create a new page every single time OneNote is launched from the app. In order to open the same page, you can persist the returned URL and use that to Open the client.
- The Access Token from the MS Live Authentication expires in about an hour. When this happens, the OneNote  API request returns a 401 Unauthorized response. To mitigate this, you can refresh the Access Token using the refresh token, which is also returned during Live Authentication.

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey @pnavk i have same issue but unable to open webURL in my app. I am successfully able to crate OneNote from my app and getting response also. In response i am getting clientURL and webURL from which i am trying to open webURL. but it tells me can not open page. please help me on this. Output i want is after creating note i need to open that created note so user can see created note.

Comment: i am able to open webUrl in iPad but not in iPhone is there any specific reason for this ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya please post your questions separately instead of as comments. This way the whole community has a chance to help you resolve your issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533055/how-to-open-created-onenote-from-my-ios-application please have a look and help me.

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of new automation app Workflow for iOS I'm extremely interested in figuring out how to incorporate OneNote into my actions.

I'm not looking to make an app and thus far I cannot find any examples for advanced url schemes for OneNote so the ability to grab a link that would open the OneNote app on either iPhone or iPad and have it go to the correct notebook and page would be great.

Ideally we could use a url scheme which OneNote:// works but need additional parameters for which notebook and page and how to create either a new notebook or page with that.

Workflow goes above and beyond what IFTTT can do (situation depending) and really looking forward to starting to use OneNote more due to automation possibilities.